# React JSX mapping through data where sometimes a data field is missing

Tags: reactjs, jsx

im looping through data
This is react.js / jsx
If I am pulling 100 items, none will show because of one being undefined. I just want it to display "0" if it is undefined, and show the size if it is there.

**Error: Cannot read property size of undefined.**

Example of data,

```
Item={
    color:blue,
    size:medium,
    }
Item={
    color:red
    }
```

I am mapping through the data.

Im essentially doing this :

```
 return items.map((item, i) => {
    return( {item.size})
```

I have also tried {item.size ? "itWorks" : "0"} as a test, and I get the same error.

Comment: @Jayce444 Or `(item || {}).size || 0`.

Comment: By the way, whay are you wrapping `item.size` in `{}`? Don't you want just to return the `size`? That's not even valid javascript.

Comment: its JSX, I'm returning something like <span>Size: {item.size}</span>

Comment: @Sulthan yes correct, there shouldn't be the curly braces

Comment: @born2gamble well that's different that what's in your question and will require a different syntax

Comment: Thanks, I was trying different variations of the ( non-jsx) previous answers and tried to make it for jsx . Out of curiousity does that not work  in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `object.hasOwnProperty('property')` to check whether your object has a particular property or not . for your case it is:

```
{item.hasOwnProperty('size') ? "itWorks" : "0"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is:

> Error: Cannot read property size of undefined

It means `item` is `undefined`,
So you gotta check for `item` and `item.size`.

Answer (score 1):

You should do,

```
return (
```

items && items.map(function(item, id){
.....}))

So the loop goes through when items array is of some length otherwise it exits